# Change variable value only when a state changes in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state, tsx

I have the code below.
How can I reset the stocksHelper, instatiating again when the component render on stocks's useState change?

I need this class to instantiate again to reset the variables inside the class instance, because when the stocks change a calculation needs to be done to render the stocks again. And if I get the instance of the last render with the old values this calculation will bug my entire aplication

```
export default function Heatmap() {
    const [stocks, setStocks] = useState<IStock[]>([]);
    const stocksHelper: StocksHelper = new StocksHelper(stocks);

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <RegisterForm stocks={stocks} setStocks={setStocks} />
        </main>
    );
}
```

RegisterForm component below:

```
    export default function RegisterForm(props: Props) {
    const { stocks, setStocks } = props;
    const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
    const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState<number>(0);

    function storeStock(): void {
        axios.post('any url', {
            name: name,
            value: value,
            volume: volume
        })
            .then((res) => {
                setStocks([...stocks, res.data]);
            })
            .catch((res) => console.log(res));
    }

    return (
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={() => storeStock()}>
            <fieldset>
                <legend className={styles.title}>Cadastro</legend>
                <input type="text" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Nome" />
                <input type="number" onChange={e => setValue(parseFloat(e.target.value))} placeholder="Porcentagem" />
                <input type="number" onChange={e => setVolume(parseInt(e.target.value))} placeholder="Volume" />
                <button type='submit'>Cadastrar</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AmitMaraj's answer is perfectly fine but for a shorter and more concise method you should use `useMemo`:

```
const stocksHelper = useMemo(() => new StocksHelper(stocks), [stocks]);
```

Now a new StocksHelper will only be created when `stocks` changes.

> Pass a “create” function and an array of dependencies. useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

[Link to documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you might be able to achieve this with useEffect! See below for an example:

```
export default function Heatmap() {
    const [stocks, setStocks] = useState<IStock[]>([]);
    const [stocksHelper, setStockHelper] = useState<StocksHelper>(new StocksHelper(stocks));

    useEffect(() => {
        setStockHelper(new StocksHelper(stocks))
    }, [stocks])

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <RegisterForm stocks={stocks} setStocks={setStocks} />
        </main>
    );
}
```

Comment: This can be done with only one hook: `useMemo(() => new StocksHelper(stocks), [stocks])`